# How to parse json object in UnityScript?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript, json

I am following this link http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/JSONUtils but not able to parse json object.

What I have tried so far:

```
function SerializeObject()
{
    var object = {"response":[{"id":"100","name":"Guest","score":"14","game":"3,6,9,7,1,8,2,4","date":"2015-02-28 11:22:32"},{"id":"99","name":"Guest","score":"18","game":"7,8,2,5,6,9,4,3","date":"2015-02-28 11:19:35"},{"id":"89","name":"Guest","score":"17","game":"5,7,2,8,6,1,3,9","date":"2015-02-26 16:39:59"},{"id":"96","name":"Guest","score":"18","game":"2,6,1,5,9,7,8,4","date":"2015-02-26 16:34:05"},{"id":"97","name":"Guest","score":"16","game":"1,7,3,4,8,2,6,5","date":"2015-02-26 16:32:30"},{"id":"95","name":"Guest","score":"14","game":"1,3,7,4,6,9,2,8","date":"2015-02-23 19:20:07"},{"id":"90","name":"Guest","score":"16","game":"8,3,9,6,4,5,2,7","date":"2015-02-23 16:48:55"},{"id":"92","name":"Guest","score":"17","game":"5,2,1,9,7,4,3,8","date":"2015-02-23 16:48:28"},{"id":"91","name":"Guest","score":"16","game":"2,1,3,9,6,7,8,4","date":"2015-02-23 16:48:06"},{"id":"94","name":"Guest","score":"14","game":"5,2,8,7,6,1,9,4","date":"2015-02-23 16:47:25"},{"id":"93","name":"Guest","score":"16","game":"8,9,2,7,4,6,3,1","date":"2015-02-23 16:45:44"},{"id":"88","name":"jacky chain","score":"15","game":"1,2,5,4,7,9,3,6","date":"2015-02-23 13:35:20"},{"id":"87","name":"Genie","score":"15","game":"8,9,5,7,1,4,2,3","date":"2015-02-22 16:19:32"},{"id":"86","name":"Genie","score":"15","game":"9,7,3,2,1,5,8,4","date":"2015-02-22 16:16:13"},{"id":"85","name":"Genie","score":"15","game":"7,1,4,6,5,3,9,8","date":"2015-02-22 14:25:39"},{"id":"83","name":"new","score":"18","game":"2,5,4,1,8,9,7,6","date":"2015-02-22 11:11:49"},{"id":"84","name":"Guest","score":"15","game":"9,8,3,5,1,4,2,7","date":"2015-02-22 09:48:28"},{"id":"80","name":"Guest","score":"16","game":"5,4,2,3,1,8,7,6","date":"2015-02-22 08:24:55"},{"id":"82","name":"Guestr","score":"15","game":"8,1,9,5,7,4,6,3","date":"2015-02-21 21:00:37"},{"id":"81","name":"Guest","score":"18","game":"9,4,2,7,6,5,1,8","date":"2015-02-21 20:54:51"},{"id":"79","name":"Guest","score":"15","game":"2,6,9,5,8,3,1,7","date":"2015-02-21 20:37:30"},{"id":"78","name":"Guest","score":"15","game":"3,6,9,7,1,5,4,2","date":"2015-02-21 20:35:27"},{"id":"77","name":"Guest","score":"17","game":"5,3,7,9,8,4,1,6","date":"2015-02-21 16:04:17"},{"id":"64","name":"Guest","score":"17","game":"7,9,8,4,6,1,3,5","date":"2015-02-21 16:03:41"},{"id":"76","name":"new","score":"18","game":"9,3,4,8,6,5,2,1","date":"2015-02-21 15:27:25"}]};

    for( var test in object.Keys )
    {
        Debug.Log( "Object["+test+"] : "+object[test] );
    }
}
```

I see the below line in the Log:

```
 Object[response] : Boo.Lang.Hash[]
```

Now i want to extract value from this object.

I would appreciate your help on this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your log message is telling you that object["response"] is returning an array of hashes as you would expect from the JSON you parsed. Now you need to iterate over that array which will give you each internal hash object, the first one being:

```
{"id":"100","name":"Guest","score":"14","game":"3,6,9,7,1,8,2,4","date":"2015-02-28 11:22:32"}
```

Comment: thanks for response. how to iterate the Json array in unity. I know javascript and  I can do array iteration easily  how ever I am using the same concept as javascript to parse but unable to parse Json array.

Comment: "object" already contains the tree structure representing the parsed JSON. You are only iterating the top level of the tree. If you want the leaf values you need to walk the tree by iterating over all nodes that are hashes or arrays. If you can rely on your JSON structure always being the same you can process this more simply. Here's an untested example without any null or type checks:
`for (var leaf in object["response"]) {
    for (key in leaf) {
        Debug.Log("leaf["+key+"]: "+leaf[key]);
    }
}`

Comment: I change my code as you suggested . Now I am getting error message  "Type 'Object' does not support slicing."